# Bundle React/Node.js docker container with Appdynamics using Webpack throws error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, webpack-4, appdynamics

I have react app using webpack. Building a docker image out of it is failing. It is failing because appdynamics package. I am getting the error only during docker build and npm run build seems to work fine without any issues.
Environment:
React 16
Node 13
appdynamics var 4.5.20
webpack 4
Docker

package.json

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
....
"appdynamics": "^4.5.20",
"webpack": "^4.41.2",
```

webpack.config.js

```
mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000', './src/index'],
    target: 'node',
    node: .................
```

ERROR

```
Error requesting archive.
Status: 403
Request options: {
  "uri": "https://cdn.appdynamics.com/packages/nodejs/4.5.23.0/appdynamics-native-native-linux-alpine-x64-v13.tgz",
  "followRedirect": true,
  "headers": {
    "User-Agent": "npm/6.14.4 node/v13.12.0 linux x64"
  },
  "gzip": true,
  "encoding": null,
  "strictSSL": true
}
Response headers: {
  "content-type": "application/xml",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "connection": "close",
  "date": "Thu, 14 May 2020 05:06:14 GMT",
  "server": "nginx/1.10.2",
  "x-cache": "Error from cloudfront",
  "via": "1.1 40d918fb5b613b4b7e7845ec0fcf9f1f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
  "x-amz-cf-pop": "PHX50-C1",
  "x-amz-cf-id": "g6jqpEJr-dN7-e5qMmOL3Gy4dENwgp_ZFKLe-OLtgXZZ3P5T9SM5xg=="
}
Make sure your network and proxy settings are correct.
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded the appdynamics package to latest.